# SharePoint Designer 2013 External Content Type + same foreign identifier = no go

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2016, external-contenttype

I have multiple external MS SQL tables that are being used in SharePoint 2016 as External Lists.

There is a database table called `Contract`that has two foreign keys: `FirstLineManager`, `SecondLineManager`. Both these fields reference the same `Staff` table.

When using Sharepoint Designer 2013 to I create an **association** between the `FirstLineManager` and the `Staff`. Once I create a new **association** for `SecondLineManager` I get an error message that it's not possible to use the same foreign identifier twice.

I can't change the database, so is there any other way to create a second association to the Staff list? The final result should be that the contract edit/new form has two item pickers pointing to the same external Staff list.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I created two database views for *FirstLineManager* and *SecondLineManager* on the same *Staff* table. These views I use for the associations.